# Typescript readonly modifier stripped by aliasing

Tags: typescript

So apparently typescript allows you to remove the readonly modifier from a type by a simple assignment like so:

```
function foo(x: { readonly value: string }) {
    x.value = "new value"; // This would fail, as it should
    bar(x); // But this is okay?
}

function bar(x: { value: string }) {
    x.value = "new value";
}
```

It seems to me that this would make it really easy to mutate a readonly field by accident, or am I missing something? Am I using readonly incorrectly? Is there any stricter alternative in typescript that would prohibit this kind of behavior?

EDIT: Since this is indeed how it works, here's a workaround that seems to help in my particular case, event though it's by no means a perfect solution:

```
type ConstAware<T> = { __writable: true } & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
type Const<T> = T extends ConstAware<any> ? { readonly [P in Exclude<keyof T, "__writable">]: T[P] } : never;

type Foo = ConstAware<{
    value: string;
}>;

function foo(x: Const<Foo>) {
    let y: Foo = x; // Not allowed, yay
    y.value = "new value";
}
```

Comment: An interesting work around, if you don't mind the extra ceremony and the fact that you have to explicitly use it :)

Comment: I mean, I do mind it, I just have no better alternative :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347). The gist of it is that the `readonly` modifier does not impact assignability. This does limit the usefulness of the `readonly` modifier unfortunately.

There is no known way to make this stricter, no compiler option, and no clever type trick to do this. I am pretty confident of this proclamation since there is no way to discern in the type system that `readonly` s present on a type (either in conditional or mapped types). Without this ability we can't really introduce an error to not allow the assignment.

**Note** This was written when Typescript 3.1 was the current version, future versions of Typescript (I hope) might prove me wrong.

Comment: Thanks Titian! Let me know what you think about my workaround.